# Python mockito - how to mock instance creation

Tags: python, unit-testing, mockito

I want to mock a class constructor in Python via mockito, i.e. return a Mock-class instance instead of the real one.
Assuming you have an import statement in the form

```
from my.module import SomeClass
```

How can this be done? I've seen https://code-and-cocktails.herokuapp.com/blog/2015/01/19/mocking-class-constructor-in-python-with-mockito/ , which suggests

```
when(my.module).SomeClass().thenReturn(someFakeInstance)
```

however, this doesn't work with above's import statement for me; it only works when doing "import my.module" and instantiating via "my.module.SomeClass()".

Are there any viable solutions that work with the import statement above?

Thanks

Comment: Mockito what? `from unittest.mock import patch; @patch('mymodule.SomeClass')` where `mymodule` is that file where you imported `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you tried is in general how it works, but since you do a deep import patching `my.module` is not want you want. You want to patch the module this code lives in. Say it is in a file `module_under_test.py` where you have

```
from x.y import SomeClass
```

Now, from the tests you look at it differently:

```
import module_under_test as mut
```

Now `SomeClass` is at `mut.SomeClass`, hence in the test you mock

```
when(mut).SomeClass(...)
```

This is super-confusing the first couple of times you're doing this, but not very special to mockito but how python works.